# anonymous url navigation in command line?

Tags: linux, encryption, internet

Is there any way to anonymize http requests through the command line? In other words, is it possible to `wget` a page without the requester's IP showing up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One method of annoymizing HTTP traffic from the command line is to use `tor`. This article discusses the method, titled: [How to anonymize the programs from your terminal with torify](http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify?lang=en).

### General steps from article

1. You can install the `tor` package as follows:

   ***Fedora/CentOS/RHEL***

   ```
   $ sudo yum install tor
   ```

   ***Ubuntu/Debian***

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install tor
   ```
2. Edit this file `/etc/tor/torrc` so that the following lines are present and uncommented:

   ```
   ControlPort 9051
   CookieAuthentication 0
   ```
3. Start the `tor` service

   ```
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/tor restart
   ```
4. Testing setup

   ***Real IP***

   $ curl ifconfig.me
      67.253.170.83

   ***anonymized IP***

   $ torify curl ifconfig.me 2>/dev/null
      46.165.221.166

   As you can see the `ifconfig.me` website thinks our IP address is now 46.165.221.166. You can tell `tor` to start a new session triggering a new IP address for us:

   ```
   $ echo -e 'AUTHENTICATE ""\r\nsignal NEWNYM\r\nQUIT' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
   250 OK
   250 OK
   250 closing connection

   $ torify curl ifconfig.me 2>/dev/null
   37.252.121.31
   ```

   ***Do it again to get another different IP***

   ```
   $ echo -e 'AUTHENTICATE ""\r\nsignal NEWNYM\r\nQUIT' | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
   250 OK
   250 OK
   250 closing connection

   $ torify curl ifconfig.me 2>/dev/null
   91.219.237.161
   ```
5. Downloading Pages

   ```
   $ torify curl www.google.com 2>/dev/null
   ```
6. Browsing the internet via `elinks`

   ```
   $ torify elinks www.google.com
   ```

   [image: ss of elinks]

#### References

- [Tor docs](http://anonet2.biz/Tor)
- [How to anonymize the programs from your terminal with torify](http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-anonymize-the-programs-from-your-terminal-with-torify?lang=en)

Comment: Thanks for this ! But do you mind adding an example on how to test tor 9050 socks without using torify ? I'm trying to use `curl --socks5` or even socks4 or socks4a, but never worked. It just freezed.

Comment: @slm: sorry, i finally got it working. It's just because of i have environment http_proxy of localhost:4001 after installing anon_proxy. Removing the environment variables and redoing curl --socks5 worked out fine. I just deleted my question. Thank you for your answer.